# GridView in Content tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a masterpage in ASP.NET Web forms. I created a ContentPlaceHolder between the form tags on the master page. Then I added a web form (named Page.aspx) to the project with the aforementioned masterpage. I added a Content control to the Page.aspx. Then I wanted to add a GridView in Content tags on Page.aspx. But it gives me the following warning: " ASP.NET runtime error: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.". How can I fix problem? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you please update any type of code that you have tried?

Comment: this is code part of masterpage:

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="DataBase" runat="server" ></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>

this is Page.aspx code part:

<asp:Content: ID ="Govde" ContentPlaceHolderID ="DataBase" Runat ="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>   
</asp:Content>

Comment: In your master page insert your `<form>` after the `</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Comment: I copy pasted your code in a project and it works except from the extra ':' after `<asp:Content:`. Could you remove that?

Comment: Yeah @bump is write remove that `<asp:Content:ID>` as `<asp:Content ID ....>`

Comment: Please look through your code properly,its not a major logic error,its a syntax error,try to resolve the issue within yourself

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to wrap them in these tags:

```
<ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Where are warp theese tags? Theere tags are not allowed to inside in Content tags

Answer (score 0):

Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Master.master.cs"
           Inherits="Master_Page" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   </form>
</html>
```

Page.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Faculty_Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
     Runat="Server">
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="449px">
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" >
       </asp:GridView>
   </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Just make a try out of this,It may help